# Ubuntu 16.04 is not available on the Grub2 screen

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have dual-boot, Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. When I started my laptop once, it showed the `grub rescue>` terminal.

After a lot of tries I fixed GRUB through Ubuntu live-cd with boot-repair, but now it shows only two options:

1. Windows 10 (Loader) `/dev/sda1`
2. Windows 10 (Loader) `/dev/sda2`

I have tried super GRUB, but it didn't work

[image: Super grub 2 screenshot]

The volumes containing Ubuntu are visible on Windows disk management:

[image: Windows disk management screenshot]

Can anyone help me to restore Ubuntu?

Comment: Post the url boot-repair gave you. Those partitions from windows do not really help much.

Comment: @user68186 F: is the bootable usb for Ubuntu. Ubuntu partitions are the first three.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I will do it again because i didn't save the report

Comment: @bodhi.zazen http://paste.ubuntu.com/25629378/

Comment: so is it working now ? No errors were reported.

Comment: No, The same problem.  Boot repair showed me an informative box "The boot files of Ubuntu 16.04 are far from the start of the disk"